# a question about "as". is it a typo of "is"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, comparison, comparative

> Volunteers rated the toffee eaten during low-pitched music as more bitter than that consumed during the high-pitched rendition.

I have been known many examples of "as",but all are compared to the same degree.
Is it possible that "as" can be used in a sentence that uses a different compared degree?
or is it just a typo of "is"?
it seems to make sense if I replace "as" with "is".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a typo.  This meaning of [**as**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) is probably best defined as "in a particular way or form".  They rated the toffee in some way; in what way? *as* being more bitter (etc.)  *As* is the the idiomatic conjunction used with *to rate*, and [you can find many examples of this phrasing.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22rate%20it%20as%22)

"Volunteers rated [it] *is* more bitter" does not actually make sense here.  Firstly, it does not match the tense of the sentence: it begins "Volunteers rated..." so this sentence is in the past tense, but *is* is in the present tense.  Secondly, that's just not an idiomatic phrasing with *to rate*.  We could say "I thought it *was* more bitter", but "I rated it was more bitter" is not idiomatic.